# How will Identity know to use my custom implementations of its core interfaces?

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have found two fairly comprehensive articles detailing how to implement Identity services like `IUserStore<,>`, and am nearly done with them, e.g. where I have a:

```
public class QsaasUserStore<TLogin> : IUserStore<QsaasUser<TLogin>, int> where TLogin : QsaasUserLogin<int>
```

Now what is bothering me, is how to I tell Identity to use `QsaasUserStore<TLogin>` when it needs a user store? Do I need to implement method overrides, or can I use Unity to provide my user store whenever Identity needs an `IUserStore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on the [constructors](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs) of `UserManager` and `RoleManager`. 
`UserManager` takes dependency on `IUserStore` in constructor. So whatever way you create your `UserManager`, provide your implementation of `IUserStore` in the constructor.

Same goes for `RoleManager` - provide your implementation of `IRoleStore` in the constructor and you are done.